# RStudio: não carregar automaticamente variáveis no environment

Tags: r

Sempre que inicio o RStudio aparecem algumas variáveis no `environment`.
Existe alguma forma de removê-las de forma automática sem usar o famoso `rm(list=ls())`?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Há sim. Vá ao menu Tools -> Global options -> Restore .RData into workspace at startup.

Comment: Obrigado. Funcionou direitinho.

Comment: @CapitãoAhab caso a resposta tenha te atendido, você pode aceitá-la clicando no botão de ok do lado esquerdo da resposta.

Comment: É útil mencionar que pode ser interessante também desmarcar a opção de salvar o environment ao fechar o RStudio, isso evita a criação de arquivos .RData pra todo lado que provavelmente não serão utilizados.

Comment: @CarlosCinelli Não tinha reputação suficiente. Já corrigi!